# How to calculate distance between two vectors efficiently?

Tags: tensorflow

I need calculate `cosine_distance` repeatedly, and `tf.losses.cosine_distance` returns a scalar Tensor, so I did it like this:

```
  x # a tensor list
  y # a tensor list
  for i in x:
     for j in y:
         distance = tf.losses.cosine_distance(i, j, dim=0)
```

This approach makes graph too big and loading of the program too slow. How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

Loops are no good in tensorflow.
I am assuming all the vectors in the tensor lists are of equal length

Try this:

```
x_t = tf.stack(x)
y_t = tf.stack(y)
prod = tf.matmul(x_t, y_t, transpose_b=True)
x_len = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(x_t, x_t), axis=0))
y_len = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(y_t, y_t), axis=0))
cosine_dist = prod/tf.matmul(x_len, y_len, transpose_b=True)
```